# List of values for duplicate keys in dictionary Python

Tags: python, dictionary, key, duplicates, defaultdict

Apologies in advance if this question has already been explored here - I looked at different answers here but couldn't find what I need.

My goal is to create a dictionary like this -- `{'a':[10, 9, 10, 10], 'b':[10, 9, 1, 0], 'c':[0, 5, 0, 1], and so on}`

What I have is multiple dictionaries with duplicate keys (same keys in every other dictionary), something like this
`{'a':10, 'b': 0, 'c': 2}`
`{'a':7, 'b': 4, 'c': 4}`
`{'a':4, 'b': 5, 'c': 3}`

*I have no way of knowing the number of such dictionaries, or if there are keys continuing up to 'f', or a 'g' in them but I know that the keys are duplicated*. I've tried `defaultdict` but what I get is--

```
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'a': [10]})
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'a': [10], 'b': [3]})
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'a': [10], 'b': [3], 'c': [0]})
```

and then the same thing for the next dictionary --

```
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'a': [4]})
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'a': [4], 'b': [5]})
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'a': [4], 'b': [5], 'c': [1]})
```

The code I have for the above output is --

```
d = collections.defaultdict(list)
    for k, v in z.iteritems():
        d[k].append(v)
        c = d.items()
        print d
```

If I do a `print c` instead (to print the `d.items()`) I get --

```
[('a', [10])]
[('a', [10]), ('b', [3])]
[('a', [10]), ('c', [0]), ('b', [3])]
```

which is again repeated for each dictionary. How do I get 1 dict holding all the keys, values --

```
{'a':[10,0,..], 'b':[4, 3, 4,..], etc.} ?
```

I should also add that the dicts I have are the result of a for loop and not stored individually in a unique variable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I understand correctly your attetion, you are trying to merge various dictionaries. One way using built-ins (I am sure that soon someone will give you a `numpy` and `collections` answer) could look like this:

```
ds = [
    {'a':10, 'b': 0, 'c': 2},
    {'a':7, 'b': 4, 'c': 4},
    {'a':4, 'b': 5, 'c': 3} ]

merged = {}
for d in ds:
    for k, v in d.items ():
        if k not in merged: merged [k] = []
        merged [k].append (v)

print (merged)
```

(Quite verbose for clarity)

**EDIT:**
After having read your comment stating "The result I want is a list of values/key.", you can use this on the resulting merged dictionary:

```
print ( [ (v, k) for k, v in merged.items () ] )
```

This yields:

```
[([10, 7, 4], 'a'), ([2, 4, 3], 'c'), ([0, 4, 5], 'b')]
```

Comment: I think the dicts themselves are in individual strings. When I run your solution, I get - `for k, v in d.items():
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'items'`. Let me see if I can remove the quotes - d = d[1:-1] isn't helping.

Comment: Is it possible that your input is JSON? If yes, you should use the `json` module for reading it.

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you need?

```
in_dicts = [{'a':10, 'b': 0, 'c': 2}, {'a':7, 'b': 4, 'c': 4}, {'a':4, 'b': 5, 'c': 3}]
out_dict = {}

for in_d in in_dicts:
  for k, v in in_d.iteritems():
    out_dict.setdefault(k, []).append(v)  
print out_dict
```

{'a': [10, 7, 4], 'c': [2, 4, 3], 'b': [0, 4, 5]}

Comment: yes. thx. but I am getting a `for k, v in in_d.iteritems():
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'iteritems'`. Once I have that figured out, I'll be good to go (I think).

Comment: I guess your input is something like this ... ["{'a': 10, 'b': 0, ...}", ...].  So , the dictionaries are coming as strings and need to be converted to real dictionaries first.

Comment: Thanks @jcfollower - this at least puts me on the right track to solve the mystery. But when I try the solution presented at the link above, I get a 'malformed string' error which I have asked here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18837217/malformed-string-error-python-converting-string-repr-of-dictionary

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way of thinking about this:

Given a dictionary in Python, you can access the `value` by `dictionary[key]`.
In your case, the values of the dictionaries are lists.

So you can come up with a function to take a key, see if it already exists in your dictionary, and if it does, just append the value to the dictionary. For example:

Say this is your current dictionary:

```
d = { 'a':[3, 17], 'b':[2, 4] }
```

and you have this data to parse:

```
data0 = { 'a':10, 'b':2, 'c':2 }
```

Since the key `'a'` already exists, you want to take the value of `data0['a']` and append to `d` by `d['a'].append(data0['a'])`.

Let me know this helps / if you need any further clarification!

- mikeba

Comment: Just to be clear - currently I have a number of dictionaries with each having a unique value/key (& not a list of values/key) but with the keys repeated in every other dictionary. The result I want is a list of values/key. Further, I do not know how many dicts or keys there are/dictionary. Sorry, but wasn't sure from the wording if your soln. meant it as well. Guess I should also add that the dicts I have are the result of a for loop and not stored individually in a unique variable.

Comment: yep, this solution will definitely work even in that case. All you need to run is:
`if key in dict: dict[key].append(data0[key])
else: dict[key] = data0[key]`

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it is to initialise a dict and then populate it with unique keys across dictionaries, and their corresponding values without overwriting existing values. 
Steps:
1. Initialise an empty dict (say `key_values`) to store required key - values pairs
2. Iterate through the original list of dicts
3. Yield dicts one at a time
4. 
If a `key` has not already been added to the `key_values` dict, add the `key` and add its `value` to a list; otherwise, append `value` to the value of the existing key (which is a list).

```
list_of_dicts = [{'a':10, 'b': 0, 'c': 2}, {'a':7, 'b': 4, 'c': 4}, {'a':4, 'b': 5, 'c': 3}]
key_values = {}

for d in list_of_dicts:
    for k,v in d.iteritems():
        if k in key_values.keys():
            key_values[k].append(v)
        else:    
            key_values[k]=[v]

print key_values #prints out: {'a': [10, 7, 4], 'c': [2, 4, 3], 'b': [0, 4, 5]}
```