# Malformed String error - Python - converting string repr. of dictionary

Tags: python, string, dictionary, representation, namedtuple

When I do `ast.literal_eval()`, I get `ValueError: malformed string` for the line below `z = ast.literal_eval(a)`. Why is this not working?

(Pls. note - "something" in the line below has 4 or more namedtuples)

```
for thing in something:

    a = thing._asdict()

    z = ast.literal_eval(a)
    print z
```

If I do a simple `print a`, I get

```
OrderedDict([('a', 0.0), ('b', 0.0), ('c', 0.0), ('d', 100.0)])
```

Without `ast.literal_eval(a)`, when I try to use "a" as a dictionary, it raises `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'items'`. Here's the expanded code --

```
for thing in something:

    a = thing._asdict()
    print a


    z = ast.literal_eval(a)
    print a



    d = {}
    for in_d in z:

        for k, v in in_d.iteritems():
            d.setdefault(k, []).append(v)  
            print d

    merged = {}
    for d in z:
        d=d[1:-1]

        for k, v in d.items():
            if k not in merged: merged [k] = []
            merged [k].append (v)
            print merged
```

Edit: When I try json.loads(thing), I get `TypeError: expected string or buffer`. So I think `thing` is not a string. Then I don't know why it is complaining that it is a `str object` when I use it.

Comment: What the hell kind of objects are these that return the `repr()` of an `OrderedDict` from an `_asdict()` method?

Comment: I guess I was confused between 'dict' and 'OrderedDict'. I mention a further result in a comment on "alecxe"'s answer below.