# Python - Select first first key-value pair from dictionary when it contains duplicate keys

Tags: python, dictionary

I am converting lists to dictionary...the dictionary may contain duplicate key value pairs. Python Dictionary returns key value pairs based on the last occurrence in the input data. How can i take first key-value pairs from the dictionary when a key repeats multiple times?

i see one solution as mentioned in following link, i need to create list of values for key and then take first element from the values list.
[List of values for duplicate keys in dictionary Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18835392/list-of-values-for-duplicate-keys-in-dictionary-python])

Is there any other better way to do this?

Comment: The question does not seem to be clear. From what we know python dictionaries cannot contain duplicate keys ref https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries

Answer (score 3):

You can just iterate through your list backwards using [`reversed`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#reversed) when constructing the dictionary. The constructed dictionary will then only contain the first values of the original list.